Inconsistency Date and Classes - FullCalendar v6
Problem Description
I am using FullCalendar to display events on a calendar, but I've noticed inconsistencies in the dates shown. Specifically, the calendar cells don't seem to match the event dates, causing the background colors not to apply correctly. Below, I break down the potential causes and their effects:
Potential Causes of the Problem
Time Zone Differences:
Dates in JavaScript include time zone information. If not handled properly, it can cause compared dates not to match even though they represent the same day.
Example: Sun Jun 09 2024 20:00:00 GMT-0400 and Sun Jun 09 2024 00:00:00 GMT-0400 represent the same day but may be treated differently if the time is considered.
Date Format:
The way dates are formatted and compared can cause discrepancies. FullCalendar may handle dates in UTC, while my code might be using the local time zone.
HTML Attributes:
The data-date attribute in the calendar cells must match the event dates correctly. If this attribute is not set correctly, comparisons will fail.
Observed Effects
Inconsistencies in Color Rendering:
Calendar cells might not have the expected background color because the dates are not compared correctly.
Example: A holiday cell might not be marked as such because the date comparison fails.
Problem Diagnosis
Direct Date Comparison:
In the provided code, event dates are compared directly with the calendar cell dates. If these dates include different time zones or formats, the comparison will fail.
Verification of Date Attributes:
I need to ensure that the data-date attribute of each calendar cell is set correctly and compared consistently with the event dates.
...
export class InicioComponent implements OnInit {

...

ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.calendarOptions = {
      ...opcionesCalendario,
      events: (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) => {
        const { start } = fetchInfo;
        this.portalFuncionarioService.CalendarioGetItems(start).subscribe({
          next: (response) => {
            this.EventosCalendario = response.Data.map((item) => ({
              date: new Date(item.Dia),
              ...item,
            }));
            successCallback(this.EventosCalendario);
            this.updateDayColors();
          },
        });
      },
      eventColor: 'transparent',
      dayCellDidMount: (info) => this.changeDayColor(info),
    };

  }
...

updateDayColors() {
    const calendarEl = document.querySelector('.full-calendar-custom') as HTMLElement;
    const days = calendarEl.querySelectorAll('.fc-daygrid-day');
    days.forEach(day => {
      const date = new Date(day.getAttribute('data-date'));
      this.changeDayColor({ date, el: day });
    });
  }

  changeDayColor(info: any) {
    const eventos = this.EventosCalendario;
    if (!eventos) {
      return;
    }
    //console.log('Day cell info:', info.date, info.el); // Depuración adicional para verificar las celdas
    eventos.forEach(evento => {
      const eventoDate = new Date(evento.Dia);
      //console.log('Comparing event date and cell date:', eventoDate, info.date); // Más detalles de depuración
      if (eventoDate.toISOString().split('T')[0] === info.date.toISOString().split('T')[0]) {
        if (evento.Feriado) {
          console.log('Day cell info:', info.date, info.el);
          console.log('Inhabil o Feriado:', eventoDate, info.date);
          console.log('Comparing event date and cell date:', eventoDate, info.date); 
          info.el.style.backgroundColor = '#ffcccc'; // Días inhabilitados o feriados
        } else {
          info.el.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'; // Otros días
        }
      }
    });
  }
...

}
const opcionesCalendario: CalendarOptions = {
  plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
  initialDate: new Date(),
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  firstDay: 1,
  fixedWeekCount: true,
  showNonCurrentDates: false,
  editable: false,
  weekends: true,
  dayMaxEvents: true,
  locale: esLocale,
  headerToolbar: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'today',
  },
};[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/4c9Fn5Lj.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/4c9Fn5Lj.png)

Help to make the code work

Instead of all this cumbersome and delicate code, why not just have your server output some background events which will colour the days correctly. Then you can easily and efficiently have the server calculate which days should have the background on it, based on the data in its database, and set the colour as a property of the event.
